# Async ServiceActivator in Spring Integration 4.3

Tags: spring-integration

Spring Integration 4.3 introduced async ServiceActivators, but I don't see how I use them without XML configuration.

The relevant Issue https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3945 mentions adding the feature to `@ServiceActivator`, but it seems this was not implemented.

Documentation mentions:

> Starting with version 4.3, you can now set the async attribute to true (setAsync(true) when using Java configuration).

But it does not mention on which object to call that method. It seems to me that you have to define a message handler bean explicitly to call the method on that.
Usually this is not necessary, defining the target bean with the `@ServiceActivator` annotated method is sufficient.

Either I'm missing something, or annotation based configuration has been left out of this feature. Can anyone shed light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct; it's not currently supported for annotated POJO methods.

You can work around it with a configurer bean (autowire the message handler and set the async flag)...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So40962780Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So40962780Application.class, args);
    }

    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "in", poller = @Poller(fixedRate = "5000"))
    public String gen() {
        return "foo";
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "in", outputChannel = "out")
    public ListenableFuture<String> foo(String in) {
        SettableListenableFuture<String> future = new SettableListenableFuture<>();
        future.set(in.toUpperCase());
        return future;
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "out")
    public void syso(Object payload) {
        System.out.println(payload);
    }

    @Bean
    public AsyncConfigurer asyncConfigurer() {
        return new AsyncConfigurer();
    }

    public static class AsyncConfigurer {

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("so40962780Application.foo.serviceActivator.handler")
        private AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler fooHandler;

        @PostConstruct
        public void configureAsync() {
            this.fooHandler.setAsync(true);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, nice workaround, I would not have come up with it myself.I'm curious though why it is not supported in the annotation, as it seemed to have been intended to so. An oversight? Or some unexpected kind of difficulty? On first sight, it seems to be straightforward to add.

Comment: Just an oversight. The factory bean supports it but not the annotation. Feel free to open a JIRA issue.